# What does it mean for two partitions to be adjacent?

Tags: partitioning, merge

I keep reading that to merge two partitions, they must be adjacent.  But I haven't found any definition of the word "adjacent" in this context.  How do I tell whether two partitions are adjacent?

Comment: Here you go http://www.thefreedictionary.com/adjacent,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Adjacent" means "right next to", so, if your partitions (called A, B, C, and D for this explanation) are physically laid out on the disk like this:

```
AAAAAAABBBBBBBCCCCCCCDDDDDDD
```

the, A and B are adjacent, B and C are adjacent, C and D are adjacent. No other pairs are adjacent. "Only adjacent partitions can be merged" makes sense when one considers how merging A and B happens, giving

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAACCCCCCCDDDDDDD
```

You can tell by looking at `gparted`'s display - if the partitions are next to each other, then they ARE adjacent.

Answer (score 9):

First of all, you cannot merge partitions. You can delete one, and resize the other to use the now-free space additionally.

[image]

In this picture, the partitions `hda1` and `hda3` are adjacent, they could be "merged" by, e.g. backing up the data on `hda3`, deleting this partition, which would result in 7GiB of unallocated space between `hda1` and the extended partition `hda4` and the **loss of all files in `hda3`**. Now, one could resize `hda1` to use this free space, too, and then put the files back on there.

`hda1` and `hda4` are not adjacent, as there is a partition in between.

Comment: Also, note that doing as the_Seppi suggests will result in the loss of all data on `/dev/hda3` -- after all, it's been *deleted* before `/dev/hda1` is expanded. If you truly want to merge two partitions (which to my mind implies preserving the data on both), you must copy the data from one to the other before deleting the one and expanding the other. As a side note, many people talk about "unallocated partitions," but that's an oxymoron -- a partition is, by definition, allocated space. Unallocated space is, also by definition, not partitioned.

Comment: @RodSmith is it possible to allocate free space by removing hda1 and resizing  hda3 ? (not to remove data that is in dha3)

Comment: @grep, yes; however, that's a more involved operation. Filesystems are typically defined relative to their start points, and deleting `hda1` and expanding `hda3` (in this specific example) necessarily involves changing the start point of `hda3`. Essentially, after `hda1` is deleted, `hda3` will be moved and then expanded. Tools like GParted will take care of the details, but the operation will take more time and be more risky than one that involves moving only the endpoint of a partition/filesystem.

Answer (score 2):

This image may make it a little clearer:

[image]

Partitions are physically next to each other on a hard drive, like this:

[image]

So you can't just make green and purple into one partition. You first have to make them next to each other, then swap them. These are the steps the computer does:

1. Remove Red (free space)
2. Remove Green (free space)
3. Add Red (if wanted, at center)
4. Stretch purple (make the free space the same format, e.g. `ext4`)

The grey (unallocated) at the end of my image can't be part of `/dev/sda1` because there is `/dev/sda5` in the way.

Comment: If you want to keep the red partition, I think you'd have to remove green, copy red into the space previously occupied by green, remove the old red, and then move and expand purple.

Comment: @DavidZ yes, assuming red fits into green.