# Problem when i try to add an unallocated space to a existing partition /dev/sda8 /home

Tags: partitioning, mount, gparted, unallocated

Before writing this post I have try two way to resolve this problem.
I attack the screenshot of my gparted which I would add the unallocated space to the `/dev/sda8` `/home`.

First way: I used the command `umount -l /dev/sda8`(I used command line because it's impossible to unmount from gui ----> `error: device is busy` to unmount the space and then I tried `sudo resize2fs /dev/sda8` but I have this output --> `The filesystem is already 36621056 blocks long Nothing to do!.`

Second way: run mint in live and through this I tried to modify with gparted the partition space `/dev/sda8` but when  click on the bottom resize it's impossible to grow the space, as there isn't an unallocated space.

So how can I try to resolve this problem?

[image: gparted screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add unallocated space to a partition only if it is next to the partition -- you have a swap partition between sda8 and the free space.  Delete the swap partition, grow the sda8 into the now contiguous free space, leaving enough to recreate the swap partition after sda8.  If you use gparted, it will run resize2fs in the background for you.  If you use other partition managers, they may not run resize2fs, so you'd have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The free space is not adjacent to `/dev/sda8`. You will have to move `/dev/sda9` right, and the "free space" left. See this[1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624616/what-does-it-mean-for-two-partitions-to-be-adjacent/624625#624625)