# How to merge my unallocated to root partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

How to merge this unallocated space to my root partition.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does it mean for two partitions to be adjacent?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624616/what-does-it-mean-for-two-partitions-to-be-adjacent)

Comment: The partitions must be adjacent. You'll have to move each intervening partion right, until `Unused` is next you your root partition.

Comment: Did you try booting with a live CD/pendrive, move the partitions so you can increase root partition using the unallocated space?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, editing partitions always comes with the risk of data loss, so please back up your system first. If you use a laptop, make sure your power supply is connected properly, you don't want to run out of battery while performing such actions.

You can't edit partitions while they are mounted, so you have to boot from your installer medium (USB,DVD) and choose the `Try Ubuntu without installing` option. Then open GParted. Now perform the following steps:

1. Select the swap-partition `sda6` with a right-click and choose `swapoff`
2. Select the extended partition `sda2` with a right-click, choose `Resize/Move` and increase the size of this partition to the right.
3. Select the swap-partition `sda6` with a right-click, choose `Resize/Move`and move the partition to the right.
4. Select the data-partition `sda5` with a right-click, choose `Resize/Move` and move the partition to the right. This will take some time, 66GB of data have to be moved, be patient.
5. Select the extended partition `sda2` with a right-click, choose `Resize/Move` and decrease the size of this partition on it's left end.
6. Select your system-partition `sda1` with a right-click, choose `Resize/Move` and increase the size of the partition to the right.

After each step click the `Apply`-button (the small green check-mark in GParted's toolbar).

Comment: +1. This should work but there is a risk, which you say. So there should be a backup. And if there is a backup (backed up *files*), I think it would be easier and faster to remove the content of the extended partition, and then the extended partition will be very easy to shrink and/or move and use the created unallocated space near the root partition to grow that partition. Afterwards it is easy and fast to create logical partitions again and copy back the data. The swap partition can be created (and needs no restore of data). But make its UUID match the swap line in the file `/etc/fstab`.